# The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Int32' type to the 'System.String' type is not valid when using stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that looks like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_SearchUnit]
    @UnitName VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        b.NewBuildingId,
        b.NewBuildingName,
        u.PropertyUnitId,
        u.[Owner],
        p.FirstName,
        p.MiddleName,
        p.LastName,
        u.ParkingAreaSqMeters,
        u.PostingDateTime,
        u.TypeOfUnit,
        u.UnitName,
        u.WithParking
    FROM 
        [Property].[Unit_Rev] AS u
    LEFT JOIN
        [dbo].[Building_Rev] AS b ON u.BuildingId = b.NewBuildingId
    LEFT JOIN
        [dbo].[Person] AS p ON u.Owner = p.PersonId
    WHERE
        u.UnitName LIKE '%'+@UnitName+'%'
END
```

And in my Web API, I access this stored procedure like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/searchunitbyunitname")]
public async Task<List<SearchUnit>> SearchUnitByUnitName()
{
    var req = HttpContext.Current.Request;
    var unitName = req["unitname"];

    const string query = "sp_SearchUnit @UnitName";

    using (var db = new PmisDbContext())
    {
        try
        {
            object[] parameters =
            {
                new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "@UnitName",
                    Value = unitName,
                    Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
                }
            };

            var list = await db.Database.SqlQuery<SearchUnit>(query, parameters).ToListAsync();

            return list;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

My class for 'SearchUnit' is:

```
public class SearchUnit
{
        public string NewBuildingId { get; set; }
        public string NewBuildingName { get; set; }
        public string PropertyUnitId { get; set; }
        public string Owner { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string ParkingAreaSqMeters { get; set; }
        public string PostingDateTime { get; set; }
        public string TypeOfUnit { get; set; }
        public string UnitName { get; set; }
        public string WithParking { get; set; }
}
```

Why do I get this error:

> The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Int32' type to the 'System.String' type is not valid

If I run the stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio, I get my results.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm guessing some of the properties should be int...

Comment: Shouldn't "string" accept all types from the database?

Comment: Ever tried to implicitly convert an int to string in c#? (hint: not possible)

Comment: Hmmmm.. You got a point. I'll try that.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Thank you Zohar. I will keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is necessary to ensure that all target class properties used in `SqlQuery` declared with **exact same data type** as materialized data type retrieved from database, e.g. data type from column name with suffix "Id" should be adjusted to `int`:

```
public int NewBuildingId { get; set; }

public int PropertyUnitId { get; set; }
```

Using `string` data type for all properties inside target class is not a good idea because there's no automatic cast from materialized numeric data types to `string` type when using [`Database.SqlQuery<TElement>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery(v=vs.113).aspx) method.

Comment: Thank you for that information. It improved my knowledge.